# Using seaborn kdeplot returns errors

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to make a kde plot for some data, which looks like this:

```
    age sex
0   39  Male
1   50  Male
2   38  Male
3   53  Male
4   28  Female
5   37  Female
6   49  Female
7   52  Male
```

And I try to plot this via
`sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='age', hue='sex')`

However it returns:
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'`

So I tried applying a transformation function to convert these strings to floats to make it easier for seaborn (although from my understanding it shouldn't have an issue with strings), giving a similar dataframe:

```
    age sex
0   39  1
1   50  1
2   38  1
3   53  1
4   28  0
5   37  0
6   49  0
7   52  1
```

However now when I run the above code I get a new error:
`TypeError: _bivariate_kdeplot() got multiple values for argument 'x'`

What's causing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. `sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='age', hue='sex')` works fine. Update you `seaborn`, `pandas` and `matplotlib`. If you're using anaconda, at the conda prompt `conda update --all`.

Comment: You need seaborn >=0.11 for this to work